# Refactor database query so it is only interested in pairs from today

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is from a timeclock app which is used to keep track of employee attendance. The app looks in a database to see if the most recent row has a '1' or a '0' in the column 'eventtype'. If it's a '1' the user is clocked out, if it's a '0' they are still clocked in.

Basically so long as the shifts don't span overnight, which only happens when someone has forgotten to clock out, then everything works fine.

**But**, because of `moment().startOf('day').format`, (which is a needed filter, so the code can calculate how many hours they've worked that day), the code crashes if the clock IN was yesterday but the clock OUT was today. Does anyone know how I can work around this?! Have been trying for days without any joy.

Thank you!

```
db.query('SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM EVENTS WHERE ID = ' + req.params.id + ' AND DATETIME >= \'' + moment().startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') + '\' ORDER BY DATETIME DESC', function(err, today_rows) {
            today_rows.push({
                DATETIME: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
            });
            splitRows = today_rows.reduce(function(result, value, index, array) {
                if (index % 2 === 0)
                    result.push(array.slice(index, index + 2));
                return result;
            }, []);
            splitRows.forEach(pair => {
                totalMinutes += Math.round(moment.duration(moment(pair[1].DATETIME).diff(moment(pair[0].DATETIME))).asMinutes());
            });
        }
```

This WOULD cause an issue

| EVENTID | ID | DATETIME | EVENTTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 172 | 4 | 13/09/2021 08:30 | 0 |
| 175 | 4 | 13/09/2021 14:00 | 1 |
| 176 | 4 | 13/09/2021 14:36 | 0 |
| 180 | 4 | 13/09/2021 17:30 | 1 |
| 203 | 4 | 14/09/2021 11:52 | 0 |
| 204 | 4 | 16/09/2021 20:02 | 1 |

This would not, because the final session is wrapped up within the space of one day

| EVENTID | ID | DATETIME | EVENTTYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 172 | 4 | 13/09/2021 08:30 | 0 |
| 175 | 4 | 13/09/2021 14:00 | 1 |
| 176 | 4 | 13/09/2021 14:36 | 0 |
| 180 | 4 | 13/09/2021 17:30 | 1 |
| 203 | 4 | 14/09/2021 11:52 | 0 |
| 204 | 4 | 14/09/2021 20:02 | 1 |

Comment: Why don't you just get the most recent row, rather than comparing to the start of the day?

Comment: Is this something a 23:59 daily cron job could fix? Find the applicable edge cases, create a clock out, and maybe create a new clock-in record for the next day if you have overnight shifts. If not, just the clock out record could work.

Comment: @Barmar good question. Because all the 'sessions' that day get added together. Employees clock out for lunch then back in again.

Comment: @EricN I'd rather not use cron because it's really useful for the employee to see that they were still clocked in so they can clock themselves out and they know to notify a supervisor to amend their shift.

Comment: In the full code, this check is made to see if the user is clocked in or not db.query('SELECT FIRST 1 * FROM EVENTS WHERE OPID = ' + req.params.id + ' AND EVENTTYPE = 0  ORDER BY DATETIME DESC', function(err, clockedindate) {

Comment: Can you post the schema of the table, and a sample set of rows that works properly and a set of rows that causes the problem?

Comment: thanks so much, Aneel. I'll update my post as I can't paste tabular data here

Comment: Irrespective of the content of the query, be VERY careful with things like ' ... ID = ' + req.params.id + ' ... '. A malicious id param makes that into a SQL Injection attack. You need to sanitize that parameter at the least, and it would be better to use a bound parameter in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I replaced:

```
today_rows.push({
                DATETIME: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
            });
```

with

```
if (today_rows[0].EVENTTYPE == 1){
        today_rows.shift()
    }
    if (today_rows.length&1){
        today_rows.push({
                DATETIME: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
             });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into trouble because you're assuming something that may not be true of your data: that it comes in pairs. You've run into a specific case of this (that one of the pairs is left open at the end), but it's a more general problem. If something goes wrong with the system and one of the clock out (or clock in) events get lost, it's possible that you'll have two 0s or two 1s in a row.

I think the most straightforward thing to do here is to iterate through the list from earliest to latest like in this pseudocode:

```
last_clock_in = null
for row in today_rows {
  if row is a clock_in {
    last_clock_in = row.datetime
  } else {
    if last_clock_in != null {
      total_minutes += row.datetime - last_clock_in
      last_clock_in = null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to do some SQL gymnastics and have the database do this work for you:

```sql
with allpairs as (
    select
        e1.eventid as clock_in_id,
        e1.id,
        e1.dt as clock_in_dt,
        e2.dt as clock_out_dt
    from
        event e1
        join event e2
    where
            e1.id = 4 -- must be right employee
        and e2.id = 4 -- must be right employee
        and e1.dt like '13/09/2021%' -- event must be on right day
        and e2.dt like '13/09/2021%' -- event must be on right day
        and e1.eventtype = 0 -- e1 is a clock in event
        and e2.eventtype = 1 -- e2 is a clock out event
        and e2.dt > e1.dt -- have to clock out after you clock in 
)
select
    clock_in_id,
    id,
    clock_in_dt,
    min(clock_out_dt) as clock_out_dt
from
    allpairs
group by
    1, 2, 3;
```

The idea here is that for every clock in event `e1`, we find all of clock out events `e2` that could match with it using a join of the table with itself. Then you throw away all but the minimum clock out event from that set by grouping and taking the `min`.

Note that I'm using `like '13/09/2021%'` because I was prototyping the query with your sample data, which doesn't use ISO-8601 dates. Use real date functions to make sure `e1` and `e2` are on the right date if you productionize this.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports window functions, you could do this:

```sql
-- let's only look at the events for a particular id on one day
with todays_events as (
    select *
    from event
    where
        id = 4
        and dt like '13/09/2021%'
),
-- make the sequential pairs using lag
pairs as (
    select
        lag(eventid) over win as clock_in_id,
        eventid as clock_out_id,
        lag(dt) over win as clock_in_dt,
        dt as clock_out_dt,
        lag(eventtype) over win as clock_in_type,
        eventtype as clock_out_type
    from
        todays_events
    window
        win as (order by dt)
)
-- get rid of any sequential pairs that aren't an in and an out
select *
from pairs
where
  clock_in_type = 0
  and clock_out_type = 1;
```

This moves through the events in order (by their time), considering this event and the one immediately before it (`lag() over win`). We toss out any pairs that aren't a clock in followed by a clock out.